# I want to convert this string '82,10,1,6,150,249' to int in php

Tags: php

I want to convert this '82,10,1,6,150,249' string to int.
I use this code

```
    $packet = '82,10,1,6,150,249';
    $intPacket = (int)$packet;
```

But this code convert one of them

```
array(1) { [0]=> int(82) }
```

I want  convert alltogether

Comment: `Explode` and convert each part.

Comment: Do you want to get each integer which is separated by comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
use **[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** with array_map

```
$packet = '82,10,1,6,150,249';
$integerIDs = array_map('intval', explode(',', $packet));
```

**Output**

```
    array(6) {
             [0]=>
               int(82)
             [1]=>
               int(10)
             [2]=>
               int(1)
             [3]=>
               int(6)
             [4]=>
               int(150)
             [5]=>
               int(249)
   }
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/dgl8G)**

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert the array of integer then use below

```
$array = explode(',', '82,10,1,6,150,249');
foreach($array as $index=>$value) {
    $array[$index] = intval($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have string with numbers, you first have to `explode` this string by `,` delimiter. Then if you really need `int` representation - cast each value to `int`:

```
$packet = '82,10,1,6,150,249';
$ints = array_map(
    function($v) { return (int)$v; },
    explode(',', $packet)
);
var_dump($ints);
// array(6) { [0]=> int(82) [1]=> int(10) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> int(6) [4]=> int(150) [5]=> int(249) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by ',' then convert each value into an integer as like you are doing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the alternative provided by the commented code below:

```
<?php
    $packet         = '82,10,1,6,150,249';

    // FIRST EXPLODE THE STRINGS TO FORM AN ARRAY...
    // USING COMMA (,) AS DELIMITER
    $arrPacket      = explode(",", $packet);         
    $arrIntPacket   = [];

    // LOOP THROUGH THE RESULT ($arrPacket)
    // CONVERTING EACH SINGLE ELEMENT TO AN INTEGER   
    foreach($arrPacket as $key=>$strVal){
        $arrIntPacket[] = intval($strVal);
    }

    // THE ARRAY: $arrIntPacket NOW CONTAIN INTEGER VALUES
    // OF EACH ELEMENT IN THE ARRAY:
    var_dump($arrIntPacket);
```